# How update state with copy function

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablestateof

My Ui state

```
data class LoginUiState(
    val loginModel: LoginModel = LoginModel(),
) : UiState
```

My ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel<LoginUiState>() {

    override fun handleUiEvent(uiEvent: UiEvent) {
        when (uiEvent) {
            is LoginUiEvent.LoadScreenData -> {
                loadScreenData()
            }

            is LoginUiEvent.OnClickLogin -> {
                onClickLogin()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadScreenData() {
        updateState { currentState ->
            currentState.value = LoginUiState(LoginModel("login", "password"))
        }
    }

    private fun onClickLogin() {
        updateState { currentState ->
            currentState.value = currentState.value?.copy(loginModel = LoginModel(login = "d"))
        }
    }
}
```

My  BaseViewModel

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<S : UiState> : ViewModel() {
    private var _uiState = mutableStateOf<S?>(null)
    val uiState: State<S?> = _uiState

    abstract fun handleUiEvent(uiEvent: UiEvent)

    fun updateState(block: (state: MutableState<S?>) -> Unit) {
        block.invoke(_uiState)
    }
}
```

How update only field "login" in loginModel, but without change field: "password". My function "onClickLogin" not good work, because I don't how make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `onClickLogin` function in your `LoginViewModel`. You will need to access the current state, modify only the `login` field, and keep the `password` field unchanged

```
private fun onClickLogin() {

    updateState { currentState ->

        val currentLoginModel = currentState.value?.loginModel

        val updatedLoginModel = currentLoginModel?.copy(login = "d")

        currentState.value = currentState.value?.copy(loginModel = updatedLoginModel)
    }
}
```